# Crystal Reports 2013 Suppress Blank Page at beginning of each Group

Tags: crystal-reports-2013

In the Group Header I placed all the fields names below the Group name/field (BIN ID).  In the Paging section under Select Expert, I selected New Page After.  In my results I do in fact get a page break when the BIN ID changes, which is what I wanted.  The problem is I am getting a blank page (with Groups Headers on it) at the beginning of each new group and I do not want that.  EG, the very first page of the output is a blank except for the first BIN ID with field names and the next page has exactly the same Group Header data plus all the rows of details in it.   That pattern repeats through the whole results.  How do I make it stop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In the Paging section under Select Expert, I selected New Page After."  When I removed that selection I still got my page breaks and it stopped adding in the blank pages.  Problem solved.